# next.js and useSWR makes an error "Too many re-renders" and I'm not sure why?

Tags: loops, next.js, infinite, swr

I'm new to React and even more new to Next.js

I've got an input where the user search a city by name in a list of all the cities available.

I've read that useSWR could be interesting to use (before that I made the request with axios inside a useEffect).

Once I got the array of cities I do a map to return all the matches with the request (and then I use it to do an autocomplete).

But I get an error like this : 
"Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."
If I just fetch the data, it works but if I do the map on the array I get an infinite loop and I don't know why.

my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./searchBar.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import axios from "axios";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faSearch, faAngleDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import installationType from "../public/installation_type_ids.json";

const SearchBar = ({
  setSearchSport,
  setSearchCity,
  searchCity,
  searchSport,
  setSearchType,
  searchType,
  setPage,
}) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  // States for search bar request
  const [city, setCity] = useState(searchCity);
  const [cityData, setCityData] = useState([]);
  const [sport, setSport] = useState(searchSport);
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [type, setType] = useState(searchType);
  const [autoComplete, setAutoComplete] = useState([]);
  const [displayAutoComplete, setDisplayAutoComplete] = useState(false);

  // handle submit button
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchCity(city);
    setSearchSport(sport);
    type ? setSearchType(type) : setSearchType("ALL");
    setPage(0);
    if (router.pathname !== "/points-de-rencontre-sportive")
      router.push("/points-de-rencontre-sportive");
  };

  const url = "https://bouge-api.herokuapp.com/v1.0/city/ids";

  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());

  const { data: result, error } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

  if (error) return <h1>Oups ! Une erreur est survenue...</h1>;
  if (!result) return <h1>Chargement en cours...</h1>;

  const handleTest = (e) => {
    setCity(e.target.value);
    e.target.value === 0
      ? setDisplayAutoComplete(false)
      : setDisplayAutoComplete(true);
    if (result && result.data) {
      const dataMapped = result.data.map((city) => {
        return { city: city.name, type: "city" };
      });
      let tab = [];
      dataMapped.map((item, i) => {
        item.name
        if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(city)) {
          tab.push(item);
        }
        return setAutoComplete(tab);
      });
    }
  };

  // autocomplete rendering
  const renderAutoComplete = autoComplete.map((elem, index) => {
    console.log(elem);
    if (index <= 9) {
      return (
        <div
          className={styles.autocompleteDiv}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => {
            if (elem.type === "city") {
              setCity(elem.city);
            }
            if (elem.type === "sport") {
              setSport(elem.sport);
            }
            setDisplayAutoComplete(false);
          }}
        >
          <p>{elem.type === "city" ? elem.city : elem.sport}</p>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.searchBar}>
      <form className={styles.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="city">Ville</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="city"
            placeholder="Où veux-tu jouer?"
            value={city}
            onChange={handleTest}
            autoComplete="off" // disable chrome auto complete
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label htmlFor="sport">Sport</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="sport"
            placeholder="Spécifie le sport"
            value={sport}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setSport(e.target.value);
            }}
            autoComplete="off" // disable chrome auto complete
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="title">Nom</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="title"
            placeholder="Recherche par nom"
            value={title}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setTitle(e.target.value);
              let tab = [];
              installationType.map((item, i) => {
                if (item.installation_type.includes(title)) {
                  tab.push(item);
                }
                return setAutoComplete(tab);
              });
              console.log(tab);
            }}
            autoComplete="off" // disable chrome auto complete
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="type">Type</label>
          <select
            type="text"
            id="type"
            placeholder="Type de structure"
            value={type}
          >
            <option value="ALL" defaultValue>
              Type de structure
            </option>
            <option value="AS">Association</option>
            <option value="PRIV">Privé</option>
            <option value="PUB">Public</option>
            <option value="EVENT">Activité</option>
          </select>
          <i>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faAngleDown}
              className={styles.selectIcon}
            ></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </i>
        </div>
        <button>
          <i>
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faSearch}
              className="fa-lg"
            ></FontAwesomeIcon>
          </i>
          Rechercher
        </button>
      </form>
      {displayAutoComplete ? (
        <div className={styles.searchResults}>{renderAutoComplete}</div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

After you fetched data, you call `setCityData` method to update city data, this cause component re-render and run code in your SearchBar component again, so it call `setCityData` again and then continue re-render => infinite re-render.

I think you should put it into a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (result && result.data) {
    const dataMapped = result.data.map((city) => {
      return { city: city.name, type: "city" };
    });
    setCityData(dataMapped)
  }
}, [result])
```

so it will update city data only when result has data

Comment: with useEffect I get an other error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render".
I'm confused.

Comment: please upload full code of your component to have more details

Comment: I've edited my initial post with complete code but just focus on the handletest (for the city search, the rest of the code is not updated).
I've put the code you suggested to put in useEffect in a function (handletest).
It works but it makes my broswer crash. 
I suppose I've got too many data.
Maybe useSWR isn't the right choice in this case ?

Comment: I don't see useEffect in your code. But `handletest` function has `setAutoComplete` function which will be called different number of times base on `dataMapped` length, so that may be reason why you have error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.

Comment: The code to fetch data should be put inside a useEffect also

Comment: But if the code to fetch data should be put inside a useEffect then is it still worth to use useSWR ?

Comment: yes, useSWR is just a way to fetch remote data, but it has more benefits than normal fetch.

Comment: Can't put the fetch data inside useEffect. Got an error : "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."